# How to prevent automatic file eviction in iCloud Documents?

Tags: ios, icloud, nsfilemanager, icloud-drive, icloud-documents

When I save (either create or update) a small file in the iCloud container of my iOS app, the iCloud daemon first uploads the file to iCloud and then evicts it when the upload is done. If I monitor the file's state using a `NSMetadataQuery` I can see that after the save, the file's downloading status changes from`NSMetadataUbiquitousItemDownloadingStatusCurrent` to `NSMetadataUbiquitousItemDownloadingStatusNotDownloaded`, and instead of my little test file named `test` I only see the file `.test.icloud` instead.

This is bad because if the user goes offline after the file creation, the file cannot be read again. The file should always be available locally after the creation (an outdated file is better than no file).

I know that I can immediately re-download the file using `FileManager`'s method `startDownloadingUbiquitousItem` after iCloud removes it, but this feels like a silly hack. Is there a way to simply prevent iCloud from evicting the file in the first place?